# Angular No Token found returning 404

Tags: angular, jwt

I think I'm making some mistake somewhere in my code.

I'm trying to access an endpoint that returns a JSON list of all registered users of other routes. And an admin token is required for this route.

For now, an admin is able to register and login to get the assigned token.

I'm having a problem passing the token of the admin route to the student route.

Im working on `getAllExtensionAgents()` So the request for getAllExtensionAgents() endpoint suppose returns a JSON list of all registered users of other routes.

**ApiService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Logs } from './api.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
    ApiURL = environment.apiURL;
    myToken: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
        this.getToken();
    }

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-access-token': 'localStorage.getItem(token)'

        })
    };

    registerUser(data: Logs) {

        return this.http.post(this.ApiURL + 'admin/auth/signup', data, { headers: this.httpOptions.headers })

    }

    loginUser(data: Logs) {
        return this.http.post(this.ApiURL + 'admin/auth/login', data) as Observable<{ secret: string, token: string }>;
    }

    getAllExtensionAgents(myToken: any) {
        return this.http.get(this.ApiURL + '/api/v1/admin/ea/', this.httpOptions)
    }

    storeToken(token: string) {
        return localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        console.log('get tok', token)
    }

    getToken() {
        this.myToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        // console.log('local storage', this.myToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: when will storeToken be called ? I think when you call the API service to log in the server will create the token. But in your code the constructor get the token first ? That why no token found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using HttpInterceptor for passing the token in the every request.

Your code will be

```
 Injectable()
    export class I2 implements HttpInterceptor {

        constructor(
    private injector: Injector
    ) {
    }
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            const modified = req.clone({setHeaders: {'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem(token)}});
            return next.handle(modified);
        }
    }
```

Your app module will look a like this.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [

        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: I2,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Thank you tho, but it still doesn't work, currently trying to Authorization returning undfied

Comment: Did u cross checked the access token is having value in header and local storage both. Also you can try checking the authenticity of the token using any REST client like POSTman first and then try to use the same token in Angular.